# How to post multiple rows via Ajax

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

The following code works.  What I'd like to do is change it from accepting a single value to accepting an array of objects, such that instead of posting 1,"Item One", I'm looping through the object and posting 1,"Item One", 2,"Item Two", etc.

```
!function($, window, undefined) {
    var local = {};
    local.data = {};
    local.type= 'post',
        local.dataType= 'json',
        local.data.method = 'Save',
        local.data.ItemNo = 1;
        local.data.ItemName = 'Item One';

    var myPromise = $.ajax('Upload.cfc',local);
    myPromise.done(function(result) {
        console.log('success!');
    });

    myPromise.fail(function(A,B,C) {
        $('body').append(A.responseText);
        console.log(B);
        console.log(C);
    });
}(jQuery, window);
```

And

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="Save" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="ItemNo">
    <cfargument name="ItemName">
    <cfset var local = {}>

    <cfquery datasource="#Application.Datasource#" username="#Application.Username#" password="#Application.Password#">
    INSERT INTO lru.Item(ItemNo,ItemName) VALUES
    (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.ItemNo#">
    ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.ItemName#" maxlength="10">
    )
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.cfm:

```
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#save').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'add.cfc?method=addData&returnFormat=json',
            type: "post",
            data: { dataArray: [$('#test1').val(),$('#test2').val(),$('#test3').val() ] },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
              $('#result').html(data);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="sub" method="post">
        Test1: <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" /><br />
        Test2: <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" /><br />
        Test3: <input type="text" name="test3" id="test3" /><br />
        <button type="button" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
    </form>

    <div id="result" />

  </body>
```

add.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="addData" access="remote" returntype="string" >
        <cfargument name="dataArray" type="array" />

        <cfset var result = "" />

        <cfloop array="#arguments.dataArray#" index="i" >
            <cfset result = result & "R: " & i & ", " />
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn result />

    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

This example should get you going, just pass an array from javascript to ColdFusion, then loop that array in your cfc.

Comment: That's it?  That seems too easy!  I'm going to try it out right now!

Comment: I'm getting: "NetworkError: 500 Element DATAARRAY is undefined in ARGUMENTS. - http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/JSON/Paul/add.cfc?method=addData&returnFormat=json"

Comment: Well, I can add JSON.stringify and pass it as a string, but then I'd have to break the string apart in the cfc.  Which might not be too bad.

Comment: That code worked perfectly fine on Railo, but fails in ColdFusion...interesting

Comment: FYI I can confirm on ACF this will not work but in Railo it will: http://blog.kukiel.net/2012/05/sending-arrays-from-javascript-to.html